# Toggle button doesn't go back to initial state - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

I created a quick Twitch viewer connecting to the Twitch API.
I put a toggle button to filter online streamer only from the list.

The toggle button works fine, but the css state of the button doesn't take it's initial state once the button isn't toggle anymore.

Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/nico3d911/pen/xYOJva

Below is the JavaScript code used for the button:

```
var clicked = 0;
function clickIt(){
  clicked ++

  if (clicked % 2 === 1){
      $(".listOff").hide();
    $("#toggle").addClass('fa fa-toggle-on');
    $("#toggleText").html('Online streamer');
  }
  else {
    $(".listOff").show();
    $("#toggle").addClass('fa fa-toggle-off');
    $("#toggleText").html('All streamer');
    clicked = 0;
  }
};
```

Here is the CSS of the button:

```
.fa-toggle-off, .fa-toggle-on{
  background-color: ;
    font-size: 3em;
  border: none;
}

.fa-toggle-on{
  color: #3f8223;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are not removing the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you remove the classes before you toggle:

```
// Remove the classes
$("#toggle").removeClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');

// Perform the toggle
if (clicked % 2 === 1){
  $(".listOff").hide();
  $("#toggle").addClass('fa fa-toggle-on');
  $("#toggleText").html('Online streamer');
}
else {
  $(".listOff").show();
  $("#toggle").addClass('fa fa-toggle-off');
  $("#toggleText").html('All streamer');
  clicked = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing the old class so instead of
`$("#toggle").addClass('fa fa-toggle-off');`
Do:
`$("#toggle").toggleClass('fa fa-toggle-on').toggleClass('fa fa-toggle-off');`

Answer (score 1):

you are not removing the old class that you have already added in first click.

```
function clickIt(){
  clicked ++
  $(".listOff").toggle();  
  $("#toggle").toggleClass('fa fa-toggle-on').toggleClass('fa fa-toggle-off')
  $("#toggleText").html(clicked % 2 === 1 ? 'Online streamer' : 'All streamer');
};
```